# problems upgrading ubuntu focal fossa

Tags: upgrade

Today, 2020-10-09 I issued the following command: `sudo apt full-upgrade` and the system failed to execute the command. The response I got in the command console was:

```
Des:1 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal-updates/main amd64 python3-problem-report all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9 [9.704 B]
Des:2 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal-updates/main amd64 python3-apport all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9 [84,4 kB]
Des:3 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal-updates/main amd64 apport all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9 [128 kB]
Des:4 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal-updates/main amd64 apport-gtk all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.9 [9.728 B]
Err:5 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal-updates/main amd64 bolt amd64 0.8-4ubuntu1
  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
Err:6 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal-updates/main amd64 libfprint-2-2 amd64 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
Err:7 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal/universe amd64 xsel amd64 1.2.0+git9bfc13d.20180109-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
Err:8 http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org focal-updates/main amd64 thermald amd64 1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3
  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
Descargados 232 kB en 2s (98,8 kB/s)
E: Fallo al obtener http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org/pool/main/b/bolt/bolt_0.8-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
E: Fallo al obtener http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org/pool/main/libf/libfprint/libfprint-2-2_1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
E: Fallo al obtener http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org/pool/universe/x/xsel/xsel_1.2.0+git9bfc13d.20180109-3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
E: Fallo al obtener http://mirror.ubuntu.serverforge.org/pool/main/t/thermald/thermald_1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 71.120.139.139 80]
E: No se pudieron obtener algunos archivos, ¿quizás deba ejecutar «apt-get update» o deba intentarlo de nuevo con --fix-missing?
hugo@hugo-MS-7978:~$
```

I don't know what the problem is, because this is the first time this has happened to me.

Comment: It looks like the upgrade server is down. Just wait a day or two, eventually they will fix it.

Comment: Is that a valid close duplicate?  It's not a Ubuntu mirror as I see it (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)